# Mouse click released immediately on drag; can't drag nodes

Tags: node-editor, interface, linux, mouse

I've recently switched to Linux Mint from Windows. Everything in Blender is running fine, except for the fact that I can't seem to hold down 'mouse drag' operations.

I click, hold down the mouse button - yet as soon as I move the mouse, the button is showing as released by Blender. I've installed the Screencast Keys add-on to demonstrate this. When checking the console, I get a weird warning related to keycodes.

> Bad keycode lookup. Keysym 0x0 Status: XLookupNone
> '' 0x7f9503135200 0x7f9533585b40

Here is a GIF to demonstrate the problem: [image: Apologizing for the poor quality: 2MiB limit]

Value sliders in the UI seem to work, but nodes and their connections can't be dragged - making it pretty difficult to work.

**EDIT**:
To clarify, I'm using XFCE as the window manager

Answer (score 0):

When I try to move nodes like this, it sometimes releases on its own too, which is pretty annoying. Just click on the node and press G to move it. It never let me down. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know about the translate hotkey; but this has been failing continuously, and it also won't allow me to drag node connections - which is a major hassle having to rely on the hotkeys.

Comment: This sounds like an OS settings problem. If not, though, report it on developer.blender.org

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard If it is an OS settings problem, then it only affects Blender. Programs like Krita and Openshot can perform drag operations without a problem. It seems to only affect the node system.

Comment: That is weird. This may be a bug, or potentially just a user preferences problem. Try resetting the preferences, and if the problem persists, go to developer.blender.org to report a bug.